# Creating shapes using For Loop Coding in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, range, shapes

Hey guys I am having a difficult time writing a code to create a triangle of asterisks and having a reflection of the triangle appear on the same line. The end product is two triangles that have a giant V shape of empty space in the middle. So far I have created the left side triangle but I do not know how to reflect it to appear reversed on the opposite side. Here is my code so far:

```
for A in range(1,10):
    for A1 in range(1,A+1):
        print("*", end='')
    print()

    for A2 in range():
        print(" ", end='')
    print()

    for A3 in range(1,A+1):
        print("*", end='')
    print()
```

The end shape should look something like an M made up of triangles with a wider space in the middle. I think I am on the right track but A2 needs to be the code to create the gap of spaces in between but I cannot figure out the numbers to do it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean sir?

Comment: Oh, ok nevermind. I will delete my comment. I see you added a Python tag :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution doesn't even use nested for loops

```
for A in range(1,10):
    print(A*"*" + (18-(2*A))*" " + A*"*")
```

or

```
for A in range(1,N):
    print(A * "*" + (((N-1)*2)*A)*" " + A * "*")
```

Comment: That coding works, but say you were to use nested for loops. How would you go about it then? Also, how did you go about solving the problem? I am new to programming in general and I have been trying to figure this out for awhile and I feel like it took you no time at all!

Comment: Also if it is easier to talk, if there is any instant message service you prefer ill hop on it, like facebook or something. Depends how willing you are to explain to a novice like me :D

Comment: Sorry I'm getting back to you so late! In all honesty, I don't know if there's a good way to do it with nested loops! The trick is printing the correct number of '*' while also printing the correct number of spaces. Nested loops won't really do you any good there :/ If you wanted to print 10 of those images, starting 1 layer deep, then 2, then 3.... you could put a for loop in front of the code I put up there! But other than that, a for loop isn't your best bet to code something like this.

Comment: And in terms of going  about solving it, it just takes practice looking at problems like this (or programming problems in general). Think about what you're trying to do, in this case, "We need to print N *'s on each N line, and we need to print 10 minus that number of spaces, and then 10 minus that number of spaces again, and then print another N *'s to get the V shape". Try not to go into a problem with a set way of solving it! Usually there are many solutions, but usually there will be one that is the simplest! I hope this helped :) Good luck!